# How to fix the children routing?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, routes

When i click on the buttom with the [routerLink] the URL is changing ,but! the page stay in the same componnent - The login component.
What can i do to fix it?

```js
APP ROUTING MODULE:

  
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "login", component: LoginComponent, children:
      [{ path: "admin", component: AdminComponent },
      { path: "company", component: CompanyComponent },
      { path: "customer", component: CustomerComponent }]
  }
];
```

```html
LOGIN COMPONENT HTML:

<div class="row center">
          <div class="col-4">
                    <button style="height: 250px; width:100% ;"
                            [routerLink]="['admin']">Admin</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
                    <button style="height: 250px; width:100% ;"
                            [routerLink]="['company']">Company</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
                    <button style="height: 250px; width:100% ;"
                            [routerLink]="['customer']">Customer</button>
          </div>
</div>





APP.COMPONENT.HTML:

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help!

Comment: you need to specify blank path in children array routes as well -  { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' } like as this..In your case when to redirect when blank edit it. try this... hope it helps.

Comment: I added and didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can User router link like

```
<button style="height: 250px; width:100% ;"
                            [routerLink]="['/login/admin']">Admin</button>
```

Hope it will work for You

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<div class="col-4">
        <button style="height: 250px; width:100% ;" [routerLink]="['/login', 'admin']">Admin</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: No... still... the page is in the same component (only the url is changing)